# Parsing xml with two identically-named elements

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I try to parse this XML weather info into my application.

```
<weather>
  <date>2014-01-03
  </date>
  <chanceofsnow>0</chanceofsnow>
  <totalSnowfall_cm>0.0</totalSnowfall_cm>
  <top>
    <maxtempC>-3</maxtempC>
    <maxtempF>27</maxtempF>
    <mintempC>-5</mintempC>
    <mintempF>24</mintempF>
  </top>
  <hourly>
    <time>100</time>
    <top>
      <tempC>-6</tempC>
      <tempF>20</tempF>
      <windspeedMiles>8</windspeedMiles>
      <windspeedKmph>13</windspeedKmph>
      <winddirDegree>213</winddirDegree>
      <winddir16Point>SSW</winddir16Point>
      <weatherCode>113</weatherCode>
      <weatherIconUrl><![CDATA[http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0008_clear_sky_night.png]]>        </weatherIconUrl>
      <weatherDesc><![CDATA[Clear]]></weatherDesc>
    </top>
  </hourly>
</weather>
```

I use the following C# to parse it:

```
XElement XmlSneeuw = XElement.Parse(e.Result);

//current
listBoxVandaag.ItemsSource
    = from weather in XmlSneeuw.Descendants("weather")
      select new AlgemeneInformatie
      {
          Chance_of_Snow = weather.Element("chanceofsnow").Value,
          Total_Snowfall = weather.Element("totalSnowfall_cm").Value,
      };

//Current
listBoxVandaagTop.ItemsSource
    = from weather1 in XmlSneeuw.Descendants("top") 
      select new AlgemeneInformatieTop
      {
          Actueel_Top_maxtempC = weather1.Element("maxtempC").Value,
          Actueel_Top_mintempC = weather1.Element("mintempC").Value,
      };
```

But now there are 2 TOP elements in my xml so this wont work. what is the best way to do this? and is this the right method to parse this kind of information?

I used this site as a reference:
http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Weather_Online_app_for_Windows_Phone

Comment: As suggested by Xenolightning, you can use XPath and also check this reference for understanding more: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9494/Manipulate-XML-data-with-XPath-and-XmlDocument-C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest querying the XML using LINQ and XPath, example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156083%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
//...
var topElement = XmlSneeuw.XPathSelectElement("./weather/top")
//Create your min/max object
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.Elements("top")` as below, that limit the sub level elements with same name

```
listBoxVandaagTop.ItemsSource = XmlSneeuw.Elements("top").Select( weather1=> new AlgemeneInformatieTop
      {
          Actueel_Top_maxtempC = weather1.Element("maxtempC").Value,
          Actueel_Top_mintempC = weather1.Element("mintempC").Value,
      });
```